# Fill complex object property List<T> based on string.split condition

Tags: c#, list

I have a complex object and need to fill the data based on split condition that I get from reader.
Below object need to filter data based on "--" ( Example given below).

```
Class Employee {
    public string fName {get;} {set;}
    public List<string> Departments {get;} {set;}
}
```

once I get the data from reader, I am looping and one of the column Department has value like {"Sales -- Payroll -- HR"}

```
while (dr.read())
{
    new Employee() {
        fname = dr["name],
            Departments = new List<string>
            {
                dr["Department"].ToString().Split(
                    new string[] {" -- "}, 
                    StringSplitOptions.None).ToString()
            }
    } 
}
```

I tried above option but still not getting desired results.. I need 3 string array based on above example part of Departments property.

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Split returns string array. You just have to say ToList on Split result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean to use the `RemoveEmptyEntries` + to make the result as `ToList()` and assigned it.

```
Departments = dr["Department"].ToString().Split(new string[] {"--"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()
```

In you're example you tried to make a Splitted array `ToString()` which will give you a string representation of an object (and not an actual list object) and then you tried to put it in a list.

Instead, i've splitted the result into a list and assign it directly to `Departments` and not to `new List<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
var departments = dr["Department"]; //"A--B--C";
// Split returns string collection of type string[]. 
string[] deptArray = departments.Split(separator: new[] { "--" }, options: StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
// Use ToList on deptArray to get final list.
List<string> depts = deptArray.ToList();
```

instead of using deptArray, you can combine those two statements into one:

```
var depts = departments.Split(separator: new[] { "--" }, options: StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
```

So, your final while loop will be:

```
var employees = new List<Employee>();
while (dr.read())
{
    employees.Add(new Employee
        {
            fname = dr["name],
            Departments = dr["Department"].ToString() // I don't think you need ToString here.
                           .Split(new[] {"--"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()

    });
}
```